# Python is ignoring fleeing_attempted variable

Tags: python

I am making a fighting system for a text-based game I am working on, and one option is to flee.
however, I want to make it so that you can only attempt to flee once. I made it so that after 1 failed attempt, the variable fleeing_attempted is set from false to true. However, python is ignoring this and letting me attempt to flee as many times as I want.

edit: I made fixes, but the result hasn't changed. here are the modifications.

```
fleeing_attempted = False #the first time the variable is defined

def battle():
    print("What will you do?")
    print("1. attack")
    print("2. flee")
    action = input()
    if action == "1":
        print("test")
    elif action == "2":
        fleeing = randint(1, 100)
        if fleeing in range(1, 50):
            print("You got away!")
        elif fleeing in range(51,100):
            callable(fleeing_attempted)
            print("The enemy caught up!")
            battle()
    elif action == 2 and fleeing_attempted:
        print("You already tried that!")
        battle()
```

Comment: `if fleeing_attempted == True:` can't be true in any case as you set to false in the line just above.

Comment: I think you have to move the first declaration `fleeing_attempted = False` outside the scope of the first elif.

Comment: You reset it to false every time... Also note that you can just do `if fleeing_attempted:` and `else:`

Comment: It may be a good idea to readjust your thinking a little. Python is not ignoring anything—it is doing exactly what you tell it to do. That's the great (and sometimes annoying) thing about computers. So next time, go through your code step by step to figure out why things aren't working as expected.

Comment: Funny thing to say "Python is ignoring something". It is a programming language and it executes line by line without ignoring anything. It does ignore lines of code that you implicitly told it to ignore by checking a condition that is always False...

Answer (score 0):

```
elif action == "2":
    fleeing = randint(1, 100)
    fleeing_attempted = False < --- Your problem is here.
    if fleeing_attempted == True:
```

You set it to `False` before you do the `if` check, so it will never be `True`.

You can also do:

```
if fleeing_attempted:
```

to test if it's [true](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

You can also clean up your code with `and`

```
elif action == "2" and fleeing_attempted :
    # rest of code
```

**Cleaned Code**:

```
def have_battle():
    action = input("What will you do?")
    print("1. Attack")
    print("2.Flee")

    if action == "1":
        print("You choose to attack")
    elif action == "2":
        # do your random check
        fleeing = random.randint(0, 100)
        print("fleeing variable: {0}", fleeing)
        if fleeing in range (1,50):
            print("You choose to flee")
```

You had some major problems, but I cleaned up some it and you should be able to work off it.

Comment: even after I made this fix, it still ignores it. '     elif action == 2 and fleeing_attempted:
        print("You already tried that!")
        battle() '

Comment: @rsg33 - where did you place `fleeing_attempted = False` ?

Comment: @rsg33 - How are you doing your inputs? In your sample, `2` is a string. Post your entire code so we can help you.

Comment: I added the changes in the original post just now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following two lines of code:

```py
fleeing_attempted = False
if fleeing_attempted == True:
```

There is no chance for `fleeing_attempted` to ever be `True` at that `if` statement, since it is being set to `False` on the line above.

Without seeing the rest of your code, it is hard to tell where the `fleeing_attempted=False` should go but it should probably be somewhere in initialization.